# How to send slash message in Discord using Php

Tags: php, api, discord

I am working on "Discord" with Php,Right now if i manually type "/imagine prompt ANYTEXT" then i am getting "image" as response which is correct way,but whenever i trying to send message with php (not manually ) then i am not getting "image", Here is my current code

```
[$url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/MYWEBHOOOK";
$headers = \[ 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \];
$POST = \[ 'username' => 'Testing BOT', 'content' => '/imagine/prompt/Test'\];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($POST));
$response   = curl_exec($ch);][1]
```

Comment: You're not sending the command in the same format though? `/imagine prompt ANYTEXT` vs `/imagine/prompt/Test`. One has spaces and the other slashes.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Understand your point, that was by mistake type, Anyway let me explain, Whenever i manually type "/imagine prompt ANYTEXT" then as response i am getting "image" from discord/channel but whenever i try to do this via php code then i am not getting any image, only message is displaying ( /imagine prompt Anytext ) , what is the solution for this ?